# Add CC or BCC to Magento Community Contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, contact-form

Referring to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679036/how-to-add-bcc-or-cc-in-magento/51149678?noredirect=1#comment89282991_51149678

Kindly note I test it on my Magento Comunity Magento ver. **1.9.0.1** but didn't work and it's really important to me to have Copy and Blind Copy once the end user hit the submit button in my website contact form: https://www.khouryhome.com/contacts

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: its the same code like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679036/how-to-add-bcc-or-cc-in-magento/51149678?noredirect=1#comment89282991_51149678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to your controller's postAction(Override the controller before do any modification for best practice):

```
$mailTemplate->getMail()->addCc('abc@example.com');
$mailTemplate->addBcc('xyz@example.com');
```

Just after the below line:

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

Use below code for postAction:

```
public function postAction()
{
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ( $post ) {
        $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
        /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
        $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
        try {
            $postObject = new Varien_Object();
            $postObject->setData($post);

            $error = false;

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                $error = true;
            }

            if ($error) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
            //Added for CC
            $mailTemplate->getMail()->addCc('abc@example.com');
            //Added for BCC
            $mailTemplate->addBcc('xyz@example.com');

            /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );

            if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');

            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean to add it here : public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers right?

Comment: You can add the code there in indexcontroller.php postAction and test if it's working fine then override it and add your code.

Comment: $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

                    $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                            ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                            ->sendTransactional(                                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),                                                                      Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),array('info@khouryhome.com.lb','eazzam@khouryhome.com.lb', 'callcenter@khouryhome.com '),null,array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

Comment: above is my code in postaction but still sending to one email account set in :"Send Emails To" i cleared my cache and browsing history as well as MAGENTO Cache but still one email receiver!! :(

Comment: I have added the whole code for postAction. Please update it and check.

Comment: Dear, kindly note i tried your code but its not working i think my path is wrong; shall i revert back this step in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679036/how-to-add-bcc-or-cc-in-magento??? i believe my code is broke here!!

Comment: According to the script you have pasted here in comment is wrong. Thats why I have added the code which is a working code.

Comment: I think you are using captcha module. So you need to find the action there. There should be a controller with postAction. You need to add the same code there.

Comment: Are you getting my point?

Comment: yes yes of course dear and i am searching for that module, you are totally right and i am sorry didn't reply on the spot; i know i am using CAPTCHA module and i am still searching to find the proper file in order to make the modification like you advice before; appreciate you assistance and support and have a nice day ahead!